# Rectangular Gradient in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient

I'm trying to recreate something like this:

[image]

I only have the GIF files for a set of these buttons.  Now I need additional buttons with different words and the same gradient effect.

Can someone explain how I can duplicate this image?

Comment: I came upon inner glow as a possibility.  It's not quite getting me all the way but it may be a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got inner glow to work.  It took some tweaking but with the right colors and ratios of radius and blending, it is darn near 100%